# How do I create an index in LaTeX using a custom wordfile?

Tags: indexing, makeindex, makeidx

I have a list of words that I'd like to include in an index, listed in a separate text file. But I'm not sure how to add this list into LaTeX to produce an index.

For example, let's say my document is a simple one-paragraph text:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla convallis quis nunc a aliquam. Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
turpis egestas. Nulla porttitor dolor nec imperdiet elementum. 

\end{document}
```

And my list of words is in a separate file that looks like this:

```
amet
dolor
ipsum
lorem
nulla
```

Is there any way I can use this wordfile to create an index? Or am I limited to using things like **makidx** and using commands like **\index{amet}** within the main file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I'm a bit confused about your question. How will you connect your list of words with the pages they appear on?  That's the point of using `\index{}` in the text. And a good index is thematic, in that it doesn't just index occurrences of words, but indexes *relevant* places where particular concepts are discussed.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an automated way to locate the words in the wordlist to the pages they appear on.

Comment: See my edited comment. That's not really how an index works. Good indexes are created by people who know the subject matter, not by concordances.

Comment: I see, and thank you for your help. But is there any way to do the index using a separate file? Even if it is suboptimal from an indexing standpoint?

Comment: You can use ConTeXt with the `translate` module or XeLaTeX with the [`xeindex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xeindex) package.

Comment: @Paasha: This would be much simpler with an external shell script. Not that I recommend that (see Alan Munn's comments as to why).

Comment: You could use LuaLaTeX to register a callback that will essentially replace every occurrence of such a word by `\index{word}` each time you compile.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your needs, you could use `csvsimple` to elaborate you word list file as you like (even if, as Alan said in his comment, it's not possible to create the link to where the word is cited in the text).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{multicol}

% The following code is here only to create the file mylist.txt
% you don't need it in your actual document,
% since you already have your word list file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mylist.txt}
amet
dolor
ipsum
lorem
nulla
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla convallis quis nunc a aliquam. Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
turpis egestas. Nulla porttitor dolor nec imperdiet elementum.

\chapter{My index}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\csvreader[no head]{mylist.txt}{1=\name}{\noindent\name\par}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* in case you manage to create a file with term and pages where the term is referred (the problem is it's very hard to create it manually if you have a lot of terms, and even harder to create it automatically), you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{multicol}

% The following code is here only to create the file mylist.txt
% you don't need it in your actual document,
% since you already have your word list file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mylist.txt}
amet, 1
dolor, {30, 50}
ipsum, 4
lorem, {7, 9}
nulla, {10, 11, 12}
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla convallis quis nunc a aliquam. Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
turpis egestas. Nulla porttitor dolor nec imperdiet elementum.

\chapter{My index}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\csvreader[no head]{mylist.txt}{1=\name,2=\whereis}{\noindent\name\dotfill\whereis\par}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid that it is also expected that the  index will show  the number of pages in which each word appears.

Comment: @Fran I'm afraid it's impossibile unless the number is in the `.txt`.